# Group of Radio Buttons with None selected in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I'm new to MVC - I'm creating a simple survey application with a Survey Model and Controller and multiple Views in which users fill out their answers.

In my views I have a table of radio buttons, where each row is a group and the user has to select one radio button in each row.  When the page loads, I want none of the radio buttons to be checked, forcing them to make a selection (throwing an error if they do not).

The problem is that the last radio button in each row is being selected somehow by default. I even specifically set one of the other buttons to checked to see what would happen, but when it loads it's still the last one that is checked.  I have no idea why that is happening, how to change it, or even then what would be the best way to validate a selection is made in each group when the user tries to move on.

My Survey Model contains these STRING properties:  mddbccu, mddtfuu, mddbccub, mddtfuub.  There is nothing in my model except the properties.

This is an example of one of the rows of radio buttons in a view:

```
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(Function(model) model.mddtfuu)</td>
                    <td>
                        <div><input name="mddtfuu" id="mddtfuu0" value="Never" checked="" type="radio"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><input name="mddtfuu" id="mddtfuu1" value="Rarely" checked="" type="radio"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><input name="mddtfuu" id="mddtfuu2" value="Sometimes" checked="" type="radio"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><input name="mddtfuu" id="mddtfuu3" value="Usually" checked="" type="radio"></div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div><input name="mddtfuu" id="mddtfuu4" value="Always" checked="" type="radio"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "checked" property  from each radio button.
Thats it. Simple.......

i.e:

```
<input name="mddtfuu" id="mddtfuu0" value="Never" type="radio">
```

Comment: H*** S*** - I can't believe that was it!  You would think explicitly specifying they Not be checked would do it more so than simply not having the checked property there....  Thank you!